# Why is my python automation script not working?

Tags: python

I wrote this script a few days ago in VSCode. It's supposed to open my zoom meetings every day at a certain time and I really want it to work because it's one of my first projects.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             I think I wrote everything correctly, however. it won't work. Do you see what I'm missing?

```
import webbrowser
import schedule
import time


url_deutsch = "https://us04web.zoom.us/j/79379252675?pwd=cm1NUUlSMlg4aSsyWXVwL3UybzhOUT09"
url_chemie = 'https://zoom.us/j/95643744370?pwd=clRkMDNEVTZ3dzErZWUvZWZFVFVvQT09'
url_englisch = 'https://us02web.zoom.us/j/3470923893?pwd=ejdIaVdaL21yWXVPaU9wdnBDalhYUT09'
url_opv = 'https://us04web.zoom.us/j/79683686777?pwd=QXhmVTZFZitCbUowZTh1bDFTWjRVQT09'
url_test = 'google.com'


chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'



#Zoom aleman
def open_link_deutsch():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_deutsch)
    return


#Zoom quimica
def open_link_chemie():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_chemie)
    return


#Zoom ingles
def open_link_englisch():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_englisch)
    return

def open_link_test():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_test)
    return

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(0)


#Schedule

schedule.every().monday.at('13:30').do(open_link_deutsch)
schedule.every().tuesday.at('11:00').do(open_link_deutsch)
schedule.every().wednesday.at('09:10').do(open_link_deutsch)

schedule.every().wednesday.at('07:15').do(open_link_chemie)

schedule.every().tuesday.at('07:15').do(open_link_englisch)
schedule.every().friday.at('09:10').do(open_link_englisch)

schedule.every().friday.at('12:51').do(open_link_test)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "It's not working?"

Comment: It doesn't open the links.

Comment: Is it throwing an error or is it just not doing anything?

Comment: It does not do anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the schedule before entering the while-loop. The code *is* doing *something*, it's checking to see if any jobs are scheduled, constantly. Move the `schedule.every()` calls before the loop, and choose a more reasonable time to wait between schedule polls. The code below polls about every 60s which I think is fine, but you could make it poll more frequently.

```py
import schedule
import time
import webbrowser


#Zoom quimica
def open_link_chemie():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_chemie)
    return


#Zoom ingles
def open_link_englisch():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_englisch)
    return


def open_link_test():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_test)
    return

#Schedule

schedule.every().monday.at('13:30').do(open_link_deutsch)
schedule.every().tuesday.at('11:00').do(open_link_deutsch)
schedule.every().wednesday.at('09:10').do(open_link_deutsch)
schedule.every().wednesday.at('07:15').do(open_link_chemie)
schedule.every().tuesday.at('07:15').do(open_link_englisch)
schedule.every().friday.at('09:10').do(open_link_englisch)
schedule.every().friday.at('12:51').do(open_link_test)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Quick question. If I execute the script without using VSCode it just won't work. Should I do something else for it to be executed without opening VSCode?

Comment: It's probably an issue with your environment, most likely `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`. VSCode sets these environment variables for you, but you'll need to set them explicitly in the shell from which you run this script. You can see the values VSCode uses by opening a terminal in VSCode and running `env`. Check that you're using the same `python` executable by running `which python` in the VSCode terminal and in your system's shell. There are a lot of questions about this sort of thing already on SO. If this doesn't help, a quick search should turn up the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After you run this code, it will not wait for the events that you sheduled.
According to official schedule documentation on PyPI, you should add

```
import time
```

to imports and something like

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

at the end of your code. This will execute forever and check if any event is pending for this exact moment every second.